# What is this device?

Tags: embedded, identification, device, sbc

I found this little device which got my attention. Maybe you can tell me what it is. Is it a I/O board with an OS running on it similar to Raspberry PI?

ICs on the device:

- AMD: AM29F200BT-70EC "Boot Sector Flash Memory"
- 2x HYUNDAI: HY628100B "128Kx8bit CMOS SRAM"
- SIPEX: SP232ACN "Enhanced RS-232 Line Drivers/Receivers"
- Lattice: GAL16V8 "High Performance E²CMOS PLD"
- Infineon: SAF-C164CI-LM "16-Bit Single-Chip Microcontroller"

Top:

[image: top side]

Bottom:

[image]

Comment: Whatever it comes from, it's almost certainly not a standalone dev board or SBC (like the R-Pi) It probably plugs into a larger board (which deals with power, displays, buttons, etc) in a piece of consumer equipment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a nanoMODUL-164 SBC (Single Board Computer). The pictures are so similar I would bet money that this is the same part, not just a similar product.

> The nanoMODUL-164 brings Infineon 16-bit power and CAN connectivity to a very minimal form factor (47 x 38 mm). Based on the Infineon C164CI controller, the board delivers instruction cycles in 100ns, enabling speedy data throughput. The on-chip 8-channel A/D converter with 10-bit resolution, Full 2.0B CAN interface and all other controller signals extend to 1.27mm pitch pin headers aligning the board's edges. The standard memory configuration boasts 256KB of both SRAM and Flash memory.

Listed on Infineon's [3rd party Starter/Evaluation/Application Kits/Boards list](http://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/microcontrollers/development-tools,-software-and-kits/c166/xc166-development-tools,-software-and-kits/starter-kits,-evaluation-boardssand-application-kits/channel.html?channel=ff80808112ab681d0112ab6b518d07cb)

Produced by Phytec, [Legacy Device, but full documentation available](http://www.phytec.com/products/som/C166-xc166-st10-xa/nanoMODUL-164.html)

Found it by googling "C164CI SBC"

Enjoy.

[image: So Identical I would bet money on it]

Comment: Thank you! Why did you google "C164CI SBC"?

Comment: @arminb C164CI is the processor family, and sbc for two reasons. One, it screams SBC to me. Two, it was mentioned that it was **not** a SBC, and I was skeptical of that because the board has pretty much everything you need for a sbc. Oh, and I did the search in google images, along with C164CI module or dev kit or etc etc. Found some similar looking ones, but SBC stood out.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it is not like a Raspberry Pi and doesn't run Linux since the microcontroller [is a 16-bit device](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets/2300/274893_DS.pdf).

It's likely this is a part of another large system (I would guess automotive or industrial system, since this microcontroller has CAN bus support).

Even if you had a schematic, wouldn't be of much help since you don't have the contents of the flash memory, the PLD, the microcontroller etc...